# Disable controls while Ajax call in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

how can i disable a set of controls while waiting for a certain Ajax call to end?

I'm aware of the method:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(onSubmit);
```

but this will be triggered for *every* updatepanel, not only the one I want to control.

Also, an UpdateProgress (maybe with an overlying semitransparent div) is not really **disabling**.

Maybe there's something in ajaxcontroltoolkit?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This function will be executed on the `beginRequest` event:

```
function onSubmit (sender, args) {
  var element = args.get_postBackElement();
  // May need more traversing...
  var parentElement = element.parentNode.parentNode;
  $(":input", parentElement).attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

This will disable all the controls inside the parent element.

Note that you need to include the [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) JavaScript library. I would like to mention that Microsoft supports JQuery, and they will make support for it in upcoming versions of Visual Studio. For more information please visit http://live.visitmix.com/.

Comment: i already use jquery in my page. thank you for you suggestion!